# Passing file path in Swing Java

Tags: java, swing, file, path

I wrote a short program that takes the path of a file and then does some operations on it (swaps lines, swaps words and then saves the new text in the same text file). It works and it takes the path and I have no issues there. I then tried to make a simple Java Swing interface and I tried to pass the file path using a JTextField. It is giving me this error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

This is the code  I am using for the program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Fns {

    //Indexes the words and lines in the file by adding them to a hashmap of String arrays
    public HashMap<Integer,String[]> Separator(String file) throws IOException {

            FileReader fileReader =
                    new FileReader(file);

            BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                    new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            String line;
            while((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                lines.add(line);
            }
            String[] data = lines.toArray(new String[]{});

            String singleData[];
            HashMap<Integer,String[]> map=new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();
            for(int i=0;i< data.length;i++){
                singleData=data[i].split(" ");
                    map.put(i,singleData);
            }

        return map;
    }

    //Swaps Lines
    public HashMap<Integer,String[]>lineChanger(int i, int j, HashMap<Integer,String[]> map){
        String[] temp= map.get(j);
        map.put(j, map.get(i));
        map.put(i,temp);
        return map;
    }

    //Swaps Words
    public HashMap<Integer,String[]> wordChanger(int i,int j,int k,int l,HashMap<Integer,String[]> map){
        String[] temp1=map.get(i);
        String[] temp2=map.get(k);
        String temp11=temp1[j];
        String temp22=temp2[l];
        temp1[j]=temp22;
        temp2[l]=temp11;
        map.put(i,temp1);
        map.put(k,temp2);
        return map;
    }

    //updates the file with the applied changes
    public void fileChanger(HashMap<Integer,String[]> map,String file) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter deleter=new PrintWriter(file);
        deleter.print("");
        deleter.close();
        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(file,true);
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(bw);

        for(Integer key: map.keySet()){
            String[] values=map.get(key);
            pw.println(Arrays.stream(values).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
            pw.flush();
        }

            pw.close();
            bw.close();
            fw.close();
        }
    }
```

And this is the code I am using for the interface:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class GUI extends Fns implements ActionListener {
    //Buttons,Labels and Textfields
    static JButton Word_Swap=new JButton("Word Swap");
    static JButton Line_Swap=new JButton("Line Swap");
    static JButton Save=new JButton("Save");
    static JTextField FileField=new JTextField(15);
    static JTextField L1LS=new JTextField(15);
    static JTextField L2LS=new JTextField(15);
    static JTextField L1WS=new JTextField(15);
    static JTextField L2WS=new JTextField(15);
    static JTextField W1=new JTextField(15);
    static JTextField W2=new JTextField(15);

    public GUI(JPanel panel,JFrame frame,GridBagConstraints gbc){
        //panel and frame config
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30,30,10,30));
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(100,100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("File Processing Application");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc=new GridBagConstraints();
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        GUI gui=new GUI(panel,frame,gbc);

        gui.addLabel("Open File ", panel,1,1,1,1,gbc,0,0 );
        gui.addTextField( panel,1,1,1,1,gbc,1,0 , gui.FileField);
        gui.addLabel("Line Swap:", panel,20,2,2,2,gbc,0,1 );

        gui.addLabel("Line 1", panel,20,0,1,1,gbc,0,2 );
        gui.addTextField( panel,20,0,1,1,gbc,1,2, gui.L1LS );

        gui.addLabel("Line 2", panel,20,0,1,1,gbc,0,3 );
        gui.addTextField( panel,20,0,1,1,gbc,1,3, gui.L2LS );

        gui.addButton( panel,40,4,1,1,gbc,1,4, gui.Line_Swap);

        gui.addLabel("Word Swap:", panel,20,2,2,2,gbc,0,5 );

        gui.addLabel("Line 1", panel,20,0,1,1,gbc,0,6 );
        gui.addTextField(panel,20,0,1,5,gbc,1,6 , gui.L1WS);

        gui.addLabel("Word 1", panel,20,0,1,20,gbc,2,6 );
        gui.addTextField(panel,20,0,1,1,gbc,3,6, gui.L2WS );

        gui.addLabel("Line 2", panel,20,0,1,1,gbc,0,7 );
        gui.addTextField( panel,20,0,1,1,gbc,1,7, gui.W1 );

        gui.addLabel("Word 2", panel,20,0,1,20,gbc,2,7 );
        gui.addTextField( panel,20,0,1,1,gbc,3,7 ,gui.W2);

        gui.addButton( panel,40,4,1,1,gbc,1,8, gui.Word_Swap);

        gui.addButton( panel,80,0,1,0,gbc,0,9, gui.Save);

        Line_Swap.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        Fns fns =new Fns();
                        try{
                            HashMap<Integer,String[]> map= fns.Separator(FileField.getText());
                            int i=Integer.parseInt(L1LS.getText());
                            int j=Integer.parseInt(L2LS.getText());
                            HashMap<Integer,String[]> map1=fns.lineChanger(i,j,map);
                            fns.fileChanger(map1,FileField.getText());
                        }
                        catch(IOException exception){
                            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    //Methods for coordinates setup, and jpannel configuration
    private void addButton(  JPanel panel, int top, int left,int bottom,int right,GridBagConstraints gbc,int x,int y,JButton button) {
        Insets i = new Insets(top, left, bottom, right);
        gbc.insets = i;
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        panel.add(button, gbc);
    }

    private void addLabel( String name, JPanel panel, int top, int left,int bottom,int right,GridBagConstraints gbc,int x,int y) {
        Insets i = new Insets(top, left, bottom, right);
        gbc.insets = i;
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        panel.add(new JLabel(name) , gbc);
    }

    private void addTextField(  JPanel panel, int top, int left,int bottom,int right,GridBagConstraints gbc,int x,int y,JTextField textField) {
        Insets i = new Insets(top, left, bottom, right);
        gbc.insets = i;
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        panel.add(textField, gbc);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

}
```

Comment: And what do you enter in the text field?

Comment: I enter the path of the file I want to perform the operations on, a file that already exists on my Desktop and I have tried with the code and works

Comment: Why are you not using a JFileChooser?

Comment: In my experience matching a file path to a file can often be pretty tricky. There are several things you should look at (System.getProperty(user.dir)) and also be aware that network and virtual (short-cut connected) folders don't connect (in my experience - maybe this has been updated). You should be aware of capitalization. Java may be running with different file permissions... these are a couple of things to check